# What is the point of serializing a class whose members are all transient?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton

I was reading a bit on the Singleton design pattern and it turns out that a good way of implementing a serializable Singleton is to have a `readResolve` method which returns the true instance and all members declared `transient`. I have a couple of questions:

1. If upon deserialization you're still getting the true instance and not the serialized one, isn't serializing useless? You're going to lose everything anyway.
2. If I'm wrong about 1. above, wouldn't declaring all members transient still lose all members' values? So again, wouldn't serialization be useless?
3. Are there any situations where serializing a Singleton is required if all member data is lost?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what your singleton is. Consider this example:

```
public class Apple implements Serializable {
    private List<Worm> worms = Collections.emptyList();

    ...
}
```

`Collections.emptyList()` is a singleton. But it makes sense to serialize it when you serialize an apple. And when deserializing the apple, you want to get back the singleton empty list, and not a new copy of this singleton.

Answer (score 0):

The focus is not serializing state and deserializing it back. The focus is, during serialization and deserialization you may end up in creating more than one instance of a class which you want to be Singleton. So how do you stop that from happening is focus of the problem you are trying to solve. And the solution is as you mentioned -

*readResolve method which returns the true instance and all members
 declared transient**

So true, you are not saving and retrieving the state. But you are stopping your singlton to have more than one instance during serialization and deserialization which is of more importance in the context of singleton. Hope this help.